# Кроссбраузерные аналоги css свойства zoom

Tags: jquery, html, css

Добрый день, товарищи!

Подскажите, есть ли аналоги css свойства zoom, или jquery скрипты для зуммирования страницы. Требуется уменьшить зум сайта на маленьком экране, что-то типа viewport, но не для девайсов. Есть что-нибудь? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
zoom: 0.5

transform: scale(0.5, 0.5)
```

Только со scale есть проблема - может вызвать размытие элементов.

Comment: Думаю человеку нужен https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: не, я же написал - Требуется уменьшить зум сайта на маленьком экране, что-то типа viewport, но не для девайсов